# My loop isn't looking past the first item in the array. angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My loop isn't looking past the first item in the array. I am trying to make it so that if an item is already in the array it will pass over it. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
function DBController($scope){

    $scope.itemName = " ";
    $scope.nameArray = ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Eggs'];

    $scope.addItem = function(){
        console.log($scope.itemName);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.nameArray.length; i++) {

            if ($scope.itemName === " ") {
                alert("I'm sorry, but you have to enter an item to add to this list.");

                $scope.itemName = " ";
                break;

            }else if ($scope.itemName === $scope.nameArray[i]){
                alert("I'm sorry, but the item you are trying to add is already in your list.");

                $scope.itemName = " ";
                break;
            }else{
                $scope.nameArray.push($scope.itemName);

                $scope.itemName = " ";
                break;
            };

        };  

    }
    $scope.deleteName = function(deletedName){
        var idx = $scope.nameArray.indexOf(deletedName);
        $scope.nameArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The break statement terminates the loop. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).

Answer (score 0):

Yo've got a bit error in your loop logic. After first iteration new itemName was added to array (in case that wasn't Bread) and you code was breaking the loop   Please see here @ [http://jsbin.com/huyul/2/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/huyul/2/edit?js,output)

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    console.log($scope.itemName);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.nameArray.length; i++) {

        if ($scope.itemName === " ") {
            alert("I'm sorry, but you have to enter an item to add to this list.");

            $scope.itemName = " ";
            return;

        }else if ($scope.itemName === $scope.nameArray[i]){
            alert("I'm sorry, but the item you are trying to add is already in your list.");

            $scope.itemName = " ";
            return;
        }

    }


      $scope.nameArray.push($scope.itemName);
      $scope.itemName = " ";



};
```